# Looping through select options and deleting

Tags: javascript

I need to delete options after looping through them if they are not in the given time. They still seem to exsist afterwards though.

```
    var i;
    var dates = document.getElementById("event_date")
    for (i = 1; i < dates.options.length; i++) {

      var dateString = dates.options[i].value;
      var date = new Date(dateString)
      var timestamp = date.getTime();
      var anfangsdatum = new Date("2019-06-01 23:59:00").getTime();
      var enddatum = new Date("2019-07-01 23:59:00").getTime();

      if (anfangsdatum < timestamp < enddatum ) {
      // The selected time in summer
        dates.options[i].style.display = "block";
      } else if (timestamp > enddatum) {
        dates.options[i] = null;
      } else {
        dates.options.remove(i);
      }
   }
```

sample dateString = 2019-07-01 09:00

Comment: This if condition `anfangsdatum < timestamp < enddatum` seems weird, it should be `anfangsdatum < timestamp && timestamp < enddatum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some small mistakes in your code.

```
for (i = 1; i < dates.options.length; i++)
```

Your loop starts at 1 - since it's an array, you should start from 0 - unless there's a reason you want to skip the first option.

```
if (anfangsdatum < timestamp < enddatum )
```

This comparison doesn't make sense, it should be:

```
if (anfangsdatum < timestamp && timestamp < enddatum )
```

Furthermore if the above condition evaluates to false, it's time to remove the options.

```js
   var i;
   var dates = document.getElementById("event_date")

   for (i = 0; i < dates.options.length; i++) {

     var dateString = dates.options[i].value;
     var date = new Date(dateString)
     var timestamp = date.getTime();
     var anfangsdatum = new Date("2019-06-01 23:59:00").getTime();
     var enddatum = new Date("2019-07-01 23:59:00").getTime();
     if (anfangsdatum < timestamp && timestamp < enddatum) {
       dates.options[i].style.display = "block";
     } else {
       dates.options.remove(i);
     }
   }
```

```html
<select id="event_date">
  <option value="2019-07-01 09:00">2019-07-01 09:00</option>
  <option value="2018-07-01 09:00">2018-07-01 09:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your first condition `anfangsdatum < timestamp < enddatum` if is always true so there will never be anything removed!

Your first if should be `anfangsdatum < timestamp && timestamp < enddatum`

```js
var timestamp = new Date();
var anfangsdatum = new Date("2019-06-01 23:59:00").getTime();
var enddatum = new Date("2019-07-01 23:59:00").getTime();

console.log(anfangsdatum < timestamp < enddatum);

// this evaluates to true or false
console.log(anfangsdatum < timestamp);

// no matter what you always get true in the end
console.log(true < timestamp < enddatum);
console.log(false < timestamp < enddatum);
```